# Faster way of unstack stack

Tags: pandas

For a large series (say 9 Million), I noted the unstack (converting it into 6000*8000 dataframe), perform some rolling operations  and then stack again (convert it to its original 9 Million rows form) is pretty slow. What would be the best way to do it if I have a very large computer (say 50+ cores very large RAM).

Comment: Not really worth a full response, but look into Dask, which will carry out distributed, multiprocessed operations on dataframe-like objects. It currently doesn't support `unstack`, but does support `pivot`, which you may be able to use for the same purpose, depending on your purpose.